# Compile C++ code in Ubuntu with gcc linking a library

Tags: c++, curl, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

I'm stuck in a very simple problem: I cannot manage to make work my simple code example in C++.
I want to include the "curl" library but when I compile with the command:

```
g++ -o myprog.out myprog.cpp -L/curl/include/ -lcurl
```

I get the following error message:

> myprog.cpp:3:71: fatal error: /curl/include/curl/curl.h: No such file
>   or directory

My folder contains:

- myprog.cpp (the file I want to compile)
- curl -> include -> curl -> curl.h (path in which the curl.h file is located).

My headers file are configured in this way:

> ```
> include<iostream>
> include<string>
> include<curl.h>
> ```

What I'm doing wrong? It's probably a very simple problem but it's driving me crazy :-/

Comment: What happens if you change `include<curl.h>` to `include "curl.h"`?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: It should be `-I` not `-L`: `I` is for include paths; `L` is for linker paths. You'll need to add `-I/curl/include` and probably need to change `-L` to where `libcurl` is (typically `/curl/lib`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `#include <curl.h>` to `#include <curl/curl.h>`.
2. Change `-L/curl/include/` to `-I/curl/include`.
3. Add `-L/curl/lib -Wl,-rpath=/curl/lib` (or whatever the path to curl built libraries).